# HTTPS session/cookies

Tags: http, https

HTTP is a stateless protocol, and has to use cookies to keep the status information so that HTTP application can run in a session.

Is HTTPS a stateless protocol too? What mechanism is used to keep a session, by http cookies or TLS/SSL session?

Comment: https is indeed stateless too, and there are alternatives to cookies when it comes to the session mechanism.

Comment: What are these alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTPS is just HTTP wrapped in a layer of authentication and encryption. (See [this](http://robertheaton.com/2014/03/27/how-does-https-actually-work/)). Thus it is stateless just like HTTP is stateless.  HTTPS currently uses TLS or SSL for the encryption layer.  These protocols have state, but that state can't be used by the application to maintain its state.

If you don't want to use cookies to maintain state, you could use the HTTP [Basic Authentication Mechanism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication).  Or you can send session information with the URL in the HTTP request, or in the form data.

Comment: Thanks! HTTPS is stateless. Does it imply each HTTPS(HTTP) request will re-set TLS/SSL?

Comment: Good question!  If the next request comes on the existing TCP connection, then the same TLS/SSL session would be used.  If not, then the client can try to reuse the existing session.  If that fails, then a new session will need to be created.  (If you like my answers please accept them).

Comment: "If not, then the client can try to reuse the existing session". Could you give more information HOW client will try?

Comment: @user1443721, both SSL and TLS can store details about an established session.  For TLS, the client can resume/reuse an existing session by sending the session id to the server.  If the server has also stored the session, then it tells the client it can resume the session (http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2246.txt) section 7.3